# Want to limit the depth of select box in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have this select box on http://buyitnaija.com/post_ad2.php I have around 24 options under this select box but it is going till the end of the page I want to add a scroller in the select menu so that upto 10 are visible in a time and rest can be visible upon scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set a height and an overflow property to the `<ul>`:

```
height     : 200px;
overflow-y : scroll;
```

Then you'll need to increase the width a bit to accommodate for the scroll bar.